# Show an empty row when itemssource is null in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I am working on a project in wpf with mvvm. I just want to show a row on a wpf datagrid to add a new item and i have an `ItemsSource` but it is `null` and `canUserAddRows` is set to true.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ! When asking a question you should provide as much detail as possible. This includes code you have already and reports about your effort/progress to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some kind of `ItemsSource` that is `not null`. Just initialize your `ObservableCollection<yourType>`.

Easiest is to do it via constructor of your ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     public ViewModel()
     {
          _yourCollection = new ObservableCollection<yourType>();
          //Now Items can be added, via code behind, or UI !
     }
}
```

**Think of it**: You cannot call `.Add()` on a `null` object (would throw `NullReferenceException`). So how should the control itself allow that via UI - there is nothing to store the values in !

Example:

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel 
{

     public ObservableCollection<Model> Collection { get; set;}         

     public ViewModel()
     {
          Collection = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
          //Now Items can be added, via code behind, or UI !
     }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid CanUserAddRows="True"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          IsReadOnly="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" 
                            Header="Value" 
                            Binding="{Binding Text}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Result:
[image]